# Frustration when person who asked the question doesn't accept the answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I recently started answering questions, and it's annoying when you spend your time writing and answering and finding a solution, and the person that asked the question doesn't even let you know if you helped them.

I mean, if I spend my time helping you, the least you can do is to let me know if I was helpful (even if my answer wasn't helpful, I want to know so I can improve).

Comment: This is a common occurance, but don't lose heart. The goal of the site is not just to help the original poster (the OP), but moreso to help future visitors with similar problems. If your answer is excellent, and if the question is posed in a way to attract future views, then there is a good chance that you will get positive attention to the answer by future visitors.

Comment: Also, many newbies who ask questions don't understand the site rules, culture or customs, and so your greatest risk of being ignored are when you ask questions from folks new to the site, especially if their question shows evidence of their not having gone through any of the site's help links. You may want to pick and choose whose questions you answer. Having said that, creating a decent answer is often a reward in itself, even if the question is poor or the poster ignorant of site customs.

Comment: You seem to have answered a lot of questions yesterday. The site is quieter at the weekend so maybe just give it another few days for people to respond.

Comment: Keep on answering and keep on improving. This is initial barrier. I would suggest you to look for the accepted answer and try to understand why that answer was better than yours. Once you learn the art of answering. you will get good response. Remeber the key is not the solution but how you explain it matters

Comment: someone just marked my answer as accepted, I was early to get frustrated I guess. and thanks for replying your replies comfort me at some degree :)

Comment: I would recommend going through your posts and checking and fixing the grammar and spelling though. The correct spelling of the second person pronoun is you, not u for instance. I've had a go at this post, maybe you could look through your main site posts yourself.

Comment: I am bad at spelling but I will do my best.

Comment: I recommend using Grammarly to check your spelling

Comment: I never spend time on a question until I see some evidence that the OP is engaged.  Be patient until you gain enough rep to comment.  If they ignore comments then don't bother answering.

Comment: "Frustration when person who asked the question doesn't accept the answer" - well, don't ignore that signal. It *must not* frustrate you. So you have a you-problem to work on. Until that you-problem is resolved, Stack Overflow is pretty much going to suck. It kind of looks like you are still in that state where you think Stack Overflow is a platform intended to help individuals. Learning how that is not true might already help you to distance yourself more emotionally.

Comment: Re *"I am bad at spelling but I will do my best"*: This is not about skills, is it? Capitalising sentences, not using [SMS language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) and not leaving out punctuation between sentences in paragraphs (and in other places) ***don't require any skills***. It can be hard to ***change habits***, but please try anyway. Please have a little empathy for your readers.

Comment: let me correct myself then, I am too used to SMS  language.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SMS language. Is it similar to Java? Compiled or interpreted?

Comment: @user4581301 Interpreted, instead of keywords there are a lot of emoji.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you are answering questions, you are not supposed to do it just for the person who asked the question. You are sharing your knowledge with the world so that people who have the same issue in the future can easily find the solution.

Stack Overflow is a library of useful questions and answers. This is not a free help desk and you should not treat it as such or you are going to have a really bad time here.

With time people will upvote your solutions if they are really good. You just need to wait until people with the same problem find your answer and upvote when it helps them.

Comment: no they won't, only upvoted and/or ace3epted  answers are found and then with a lot of time upvoted. the rest is for the badge unsung hero

Comment: @nbk that's... not true, actually. I've had plenty of really obscure answers on old, forgotten Q&As slowly upvoted over time, sometimes even with the OP returning *years* after asking a question - and I suspect my experience is far from unique across the board. It is true that many answerers (including me) end up having an unsung hero badge, but it is par for the course.

Comment: @OlegValter it is sadly very true. Questions ask and never seen an upvote even when ia ma the only anserer. it like the Question asker says, and like Dharman it is part of the SO charme and we have tolibve with. Of course is clearly depending of tags you visit and answer, some get more votes and some much less, so telling me that i am wrong, is also wrong

Comment: I've had a number of answers that were beat by the FGITW with little to no initial votes that received them over time. It's not really as much of a tag thing as it is a question frequency-problem, though. My personal strategy is ignoring FGITW and relying on long-term voting instead. Requires questions that go on to have high value though, and there's... not as many of those questions around these days, but those questions appear a hell of a lot more frequently on emerging technologies. Like, have fun finding them anywhere else-frequently. Long-term rep is definitely a strategy, but (1/2)

Comment: figuring out what questions are more optimal for that is... tricky. It requires an educated guess to be effective, but if done right, it's a lot less effort than FGITWing everything and hoping the asker actually returns to upvote, accept, and/or respond at all. Also comes with the added bonus of what you answer becoming the canonical, which _definitely_ comes with long-term benefits if you answer the right questions.

Comment: @zoe wwe had last yoear aquestion here that a trivial question and answer colleted 20 or thirty upvotes in a very short time, but was closed subsequentially, so the upvotes does depend on the tags massivly. Also the discussion about lack of voting must be here more than 100 times already ask

Comment: @nbk I am not telling you *your* experience is invalid, only that the generalized statement about upvoted/accepted answers is wrong as it is provably not the case. If you answer in tags with low participation levels - sure, that might be the case, but that is not how things work in general. Answers *do* accumulate votes/accepts over time, and I am not the only one who can attest to that.